# Why is the method getContenResolver() a part of the Context class ?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

The method `getContentResolver()` is a part of the `Context` class, what I would like to know is that why is it not a part of the `ContentResolver` class ?

Why does a `getContentResolver()` need a Context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I would like to know is that why is it not a part of the ContentResolver class ?

You could not have `getContentResolver()` as an instance method on `ContentResolver`, as you wind up in a circular situation (how would you get the `ContentResolver` on which to call `getContentResolver()`).

They could have implemented a `static` method named `getContentResolver(Context)` on `ContentResolver`. They chose not to. Asking "why?" about a implementation decision made a decade-plus ago by people who do not follow Stack Overflow is impractical.

> Why does a getContentResolver() need a Context ?

Under the covers, much of what `ContentResolver` does involves IPC to the process with the `ContentProvider`. That, in turn, requires a `Context`, for things like binding. The `Context` is also used to obtain a `PackageManager`.

Comment: Ah I understand the first part, So the ContenResolver requires a context is because Android system needs to tell the content provider to know which instance is calling so that the Content provider can provide the appropriate content object to the content resolver. Right ?

Comment: @Codester: More or less. Again, the code with the `ContentResolver` and the code with the `ContentProvider` are often times in two separate apps, or an app and some core bit of the OS. All that sort of inter-process communication (IPC) gets implemented by a piece of technology known as Binder. And, for whatever reason, working with Binder is tied up into a `Context`. That part I cannot readily explain, as it gets deeper into Android than I normally wander.